# Rails - unpersisted parent needs to find candidate children and assign them to itself. Then display "new" form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations, data-modeling

This code shows what I'd like to do, but of course won't work because the Parent does not yet have an id:

```
class Parent < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :children

  after_initialize :find_children, :if => Proc.new {|parent| parent.new_record?}

  private
  def find_children
    Child.where("blah blah blah").each do |child|
      child.parent = self
      #etc, etc, etc
    end
  end
end
```

It's almost as if my controller's "new" action needs to save the Parent before displaying the new form. This doesn't feel right. What is a good approach to this problem?

**Update**

The child objects in my specific case are BillTransactions (think fees and credits) and the parents are Bills. Throughout a billing period, these transactions are accrued on an Account. At the end of the billing period, the user creates a bill for a given period, hence the need for a bill to find its children when it's created.

I've been thinking about this some more after I posted the question. Since the Bill and BillTransactions can exist in many different states (pending, draft, active, emailed, etc) I'm going to use a state machine to manage the object's lifecycle. So far this is what I've come up with:

```
class Bill < ActiveRecord::Base                                                                        
  belongs_to :account                                                                                  
  has_many :bill_transactions                                                                          

  attr_accessible :account, :bill_period_start, :bill_period_end                                       

  after_initialize :find_fees, :if => Proc.new {|bill| bill.new_record?}                               

  validates_presence_of :account, :bill_period_start, :bill_period_end                                 

  state_machine :initial => :pending do                                                                
    after_transition :pending => :canceled, :do => :destroy_self                                       
    before_transition :active => :emailed, :do => :email_bill                                          

    event :save_draft do                                                                               
      transition :pending => :draft                                                                    
    end                                                                                                

    event :activate do                                                                                 
      transition [:pending, :draft] => :active                                                         
    end                                                                                                

    event :email do                                                                                    
      transition :active => :emailed                                                                   
    end                                                                                                

    event :apply_payment do                                                                            
      transition [:active, :emailed] => :partial                                                       
      transition [:active, :emailed, :partial] => :paid                                                
    end                                                                                                

    event :cancel do                                                                                   
      transition [:pending, :draft] => :canceled                                                       
    end                                                                                                
  end                                                                                                  

  private                                                                                              
  def find_fees                                                                                        
    self.save                                                                                          
    unless [account, bill_period_start, bill_period_end].any? {|attr| attr.nil? }                      
      BillTransaction.where(:account_id => account.id, :transaction_date => bill_period_start..bill_period_end, :transaction_type => BillTransaction::TRANS_TYPES['Fee']).each do |fee|                        
        fee.stage self
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy_self                                                                                     
    self.bill_transactions.each do |trans|                                                             
      trans.unstage
    end
    self.destroy                                                                                       
  end
end
```

So after a Bill is initialized for the first time, it basically saves itself, finds all relevant transactions, and "stages" them. This means BillTransaction's state is set to staged (which can transition back to unbilled if the new bill is destroyed) and its bill_id is set to the current Bill's id. You can see that if a Bill in the pending state is canceled, all of the transactions are unstaged (returned to the unbilled state).

The problem with this solution is that sending a GET request to BillsController#new is supposed to be idempotent. This solution isn't strictly idempotent and I'm having a hard time seeing how I can ensure that the server's state will be rolled back if the user navigates away from the new form.

Am I heading down a painful path here?

Comment: I would take a look at the model relationship design.  You may be performing an edit instead of new or the relationship might be disfigured.  If you gave some specifics, I (or someone else) would be able to give a more informed answer.

Comment: You should probably use the after_create callback instead of after_initialize.  For reference, after_initialize is called _every_ time an object is found and instantiated by an ActiveRecord finder;  you'd be searching for and trying to associate BillTransactions every time you did a Bill.find().  On the other hand, after_create is called after a new record has been saved, making it the perfect time to set associations.  If you need the #new page to show the BillTransactions, you should load them via the same query you use in find_fees and pass them to the view without associating them.

Comment: @Lucas Meyer The point of the after_initialize (with the Proc checking for new_record status) is because I needed the Bill to automatically save itself after calling Bill.new. after_create runs after the Bill is saved, correct? At any rate, I know what I did above is probably incorrect and I'll be trying yours and jdc's suggestions. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a new "creator" method on Bill that returns a new bill with associated transactions attached.  Something like:

```
def self.NewWithTransactions
    bill = Bill.new
    bill_transactions = find_candidate_transactions
    bill
end
```

Then from your controller's new action, just do:

```
bill = Bill.NewWithTransactions
```

Throw that back to your view and you *should* be able to create the new bill with transactions attached when submitted.  If that doesn't work, you probably have to do as one of the commentors suggested and send the unassociated transactions to your view and reassociate them in the create action.

Comment: Don't you mean bill.bill_transactions = find_candidate_transactions? Assigning the bill's bill_transactions like that causes the Bill to be saved.